# how to convert a column of integer to standard hour time in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I  have a data frame like this:

```
BuyTime        ID      SellTime
94650          1       94651
94717          1       94817
120458         2       114119
```

the buy time and sell time type are integer but i want to convert them to standard time date.
I already used

```
 quote['SellTime'] = pd.to_datetime(quote['SellTime'], unit = 's')
```

but it gives a start year like 1970-01-01 to time which is not needed.
my data should be like this:

```
BuyTime     Id     SellTime
09:46:50    1      09:46:51
09:47:17    1      09:48:17
12:04:58    2      11:41:19
```

EDIT:
also using this function regard to size of my data is not efficient:

```
 def format_time(value):
 t2 = str(value)
 if len(t2) == 5:
     return "0%s:%s:%s" % (t2[0], t2[1:3], t2[3:5])
 return "%s:%s:%s" % (t2[0:2], t2[2:4], t2[4:6])
```

Comment: You may need to supply a bit more information:  what **exactly** does the integer value for buyTime and sellTime represent?  Seconds since midnight?  Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need if need output as `string`s [`zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) and `str[]` for select by positions:

```
t1 = quote['BuyTime'].astype(str).str.zfill(6)
t2 = quote['SellTime'].astype(str).str.zfill(6)
quote['BuyTime'] = t1.str[0:2] + ':' + t1.str[2:4] + ':' + t1.str[4:6]
quote['SellTime'] = t2.str[0:2] + ':' + t2.str[2:4] + ':' + t2.str[4:6]
print (quote)
    BuyTime  ID  SellTime
0  09:46:50   1  09:46:51
1  09:47:17   1  09:48:17
2  12:04:58   2  11:41:19
```

Or if need `python times` add `0` by [`zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html), convert to `datetime`s and extract [`time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html)s:

```
t1 = quote['BuyTime'].astype(str).str.zfill(6)
t2 = quote['SellTime'].astype(str).str.zfill(6)
quote['BuyTime'] = pd.to_datetime(t1, format='%H%M%S').dt.time
quote['SellTime'] = pd.to_datetime(t2, format='%H%M%S').dt.time
print (quote)
    BuyTime  ID  SellTime
0  09:46:50   1  09:46:51
1  09:47:17   1  09:48:17
2  12:04:58   2  11:41:19
```

Alternative for `string`s outputs is [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
quote['BuyTime'] = pd.to_datetime(t1, format='%H%M%S').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
quote['SellTime'] = pd.to_datetime(t2, format='%H%M%S').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print (quote)
    BuyTime  ID  SellTime
0  09:46:50   1  09:46:51
1  09:47:17   1  09:48:17
2  12:04:58   2  11:41:19
```

Comment: what if type of columns are dtype('O')?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date string only contains hour/minute/second (and minute/second are always 2 characters long, you could do something like this to parse the string using Python's modulo operator:

```
dateStr = '94522'
dateInt = int(dateStr)
sec = dateInt % 100
dateInt = dateInt - sec
min = dateInt % 10000
dateInt = dateInt - min
min /= 100
hour = dateInt / 10000

newDateStr = '{}:{}:{}'.format(hour, min, sec)
print 'number={} formatted={}'.format(dateStr, newDateStr)
```

This will work for both 5 and 6 character long time strings.