# Pandas: extract hour from timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, delta, timestep

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47795361/how-to-convert-a-column-of-integer-to-standard-hour-time-in-python) explains how to convert integers to hourly timesteps in Pandas. I need to do the opposite.

My dataframe `df1`:

```
   A
0  02:00:00
1  01:00:00
2  02:00:00
3  03:00:00
```

My expected dataframe `df1`:

```
   A         B
0  02:00:00  2
1  01:00:00  1
2  02:00:00  2
3  03:00:00  3
```

What I am trying:

```
df1['B'] = df1['A'].astype(int)
```

This fails because:
`TypeError: cannot astype a timedelta from [timedelta64[ns]] to [int32]`

What is the best way to do this?

**EDIT**

If I try `df['B'] = df['A'].dt.hour`, then I get:
`AttributeError: 'TimedeltaProperties' object has no attribute 'hour'`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Divide by `np.timedelta64(1, 'h')`:

```
df1['B'] = df1['A'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
print (df1)
         A    B
0 02:00:00  2.0
1 01:00:00  1.0
2 02:00:00  2.0
3 03:00:00  3.0
```

Answer (score 22):

You can use [`dt.components`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.components.html) and access the hours column:

```
In[7]:
df['B'] = df['A'].dt.components['hours']
df

Out[7]: 
         A  B
0 02:00:00  2
1 01:00:00  1
2 02:00:00  2
3 03:00:00  3
```

the timedelta components returns each component as a column:

```
In[8]:
df['A'].dt.components

Out[8]: 
   days  hours  minutes  seconds  milliseconds  microseconds  nanoseconds
0     0      2        0        0             0             0            0
1     0      1        0        0             0             0            0
2     0      2        0        0             0             0            0
3     0      3        0        0             0             0            0
```

Comment: Thanks - this breakdown is very useful. I don't need it right now but I would leave it for others to benefit in the future.

Comment: It's probably useful if someone wanted just minutes, milliseconds etc.

Answer (score 2):

Both solutions - *dt.components* or *np.timedelta64* - are useful. But  the np.timedelta64 is
(1) much faster than dt.components (good to know especially for large dataframes)
(2, as @Sam Chats noted) also takes into account the difference in days.

For time comparison:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dct = { 
      'date1': ['08:05:23', '18:07:20', '08:05:23'],
      'date2': ['09:15:24', '22:07:20', '08:54:01']
      }
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'], format='%H:%M:%S')
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'], format='%H:%M:%S')
df['delta'] = df['date2']-df['date1']

%timeit df['np_h'] = (df['delta'] / np.timedelta64(1,'h')).astype(int)
%timeit df['td_h'] = df['delta'].dt.components['hours']

Output:
1000 loops, best of 3: 484 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 ms per loop
```

Comment: I don't think `components` performs the `dt.components['days']*24` multiplication. It just returns the `hours` component from the `TimedeltaProperties` object.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively divide by `pd.Timedelta(1, 'h')`:

```
df1['B'] = df1['A'] / pd.Timedelta(1, 'h')
```

The result is float.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html